# All Github commits gone after push

Tags: git, github, git-push

I wanted to download my project from github without useing the "git clone" command. So i followed this guide

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Add existing project files to Git"
git remote add origin https://github.com/cameronmcnz/example-website.git
git push -u -f origin master
```

After doing that, all of our 1000+ commits where gone! Is there anything at all we can do to get our commits back?

Any help is preciated!

Comment: If this were a local Git repository, you would use `git reflog` to reset `master` to what it was before the ill-advised `push -f`. I don't know what the equivalent for something hosted on GitHub is. This might help. https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f

Comment: That guide is likely for populating a *new* GitHub repository with a local repository, not downloading an existing repository with commits.

Comment: Just push the master branch again from a different clone of that repo. Oh, and btw, `--force` is never (to my knowledge) required, at most I use `--force-with-lease`.

Comment: i found that there is a tree in github that contains all of out commits, and this message is present:

This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.

The branch name is a bunch of numbers. Is there anyway to use this to get it back to the main branch?

Comment: Side Note, the fact that you said "to get **our** commits back" means surely someone else could force push `master` back out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you ran `git init` in such a way as to create a *new* repository (rather than "reinitialize" an existing one), that's exactly what you should expect from that sequence of commands.  (Side note: it is of course fine to experiment with things, [to see what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mExi4NuLn9Y), but as a general rule, unless you're aware of larger constraints, never experiment with something particularly precious.)

> After [using `git push --force`], all of our 1000+ commits were gone!

Technically, they're not actually *gone*.  You just can't *find them*.<sup>1</sup>  *Git* needs a commit's hash ID to look it up.  To that extent, Git provides us—humans—with *names:* branch names, tag names, and other such names.  These names have associated hash IDs; if they're commit hash IDs, that lets us find those commits directly by that name.  If they're tag-object hash IDs, that lets us *indirectly* find a commit.<sup>2</sup>

Since each commit stores, in its metadata, a list—usually just one element long—of *previous* commits, we need only find the *last* commit in some chain this way.  That commit will lead us (and Git) backwards through history.  And this in turn is the answer to your question:

> Is there anything at all we can do to get our commits back?

If you can *find the hash ID of the latest commit* on the branch name that you told GitHub to overwrite with this other commit hash ID, you can get those other commits back from GitHub.  This depends on two things *about* GitHub:

1. They always let you access any commit by its raw hash ID.<sup>3</sup>
2. They never *discard* un-find-able commits.

Most Git implementations have tricks to permanently eject and forget commits that nobody can find by starting with some directly-find-able name like a branch or tag name.  But GitHub in particular have this turned off for hosted repositories (for GitHub-specific reasons).  This means that if you can find a hash ID, you can run:

```
git fetch origin <full-hash-id>:refs/heads/recovered
```

and now you have, in your *local* repository, a new branch named `recovered` that points to the commit you found.  If that's the *last* commit in the chain, you can use `git log recovered` to see all your commits.  If it's not the last one, you can keep looking for still-later commits.

Note that pull requests and other items exist in the GitHub-specific add-on database that GitHub maintain for your GitHub repository.   This is what allows you to do things like issue management and pull requests in the first place.  Importantly (for you), these will sometimes have hash IDs in them, or other links by which you can find the hash ID, after which you can use the above kind of `git fetch` to obtain those commits.

Note also that if you find a hash ID of a commit from, say, a month ago, and use:

```
git fetch origin <hash-id>:refs/heads/recovered
```

to create a new `recovered` branch, and later find another hash ID, you can run:

```
git fetch origin <new-hash-id>:recovered
```

(you no longer have to spell out `refs/heads/recovered`, though you can if you want to) and your Git will figure out whether that's really a *later* commit and if so, "add on" to your `recovered` branch.  If it's an *earlier* commit, your Git will say that this `git fetch` operation is not a "fast-forward" and refuse to *drop* commits from your `recovered` branch.

This is/is-not a "fast forward" test is the same way that `git push origin <name>` avoids "losing" commits from your GitHub repository.  Using `--force`, which exists for both fetch and push, *overrides* this protection.  That's why the `git push --force` you ran lost your commits: you overrode the usual protection.

---

<sup>1</sup>If Dr Livingstone is lost in Africa, does he really exist?  [Henry Morton Stanley says yes](https://www.history.com/news/when-stanley-met-livingstone), but on the other hand, he *found* Livingstone.  Later, he experimented with King Leopold II and the Congo river area, to tragic effect.

<sup>2</sup>An annotated tag object can refer to a tree or blob, or even to another annotated tag object, but this is unusual: most refer to commits.

<sup>3</sup>This is required to use the fancy new "partial clone" feature introduced in Git version 2.18 or so.  (Pieces were in 2.17, and things didn't really work well until much more recently.  But 2.18 is when the protocol was deliberately loosened.  There are still rough edges with partial clones, but as of Git 2.32 or so they seem to be fairly usable.)

Comment: Does `git fetch origin <hash-id>` generally work on orphaned commits, or would that be implementation dependent? I just tried on AzureDevOps on a really old commit from years ago and it worked. (Because AFAIK AzDO, like GitHub, keeps all commits forever.)

Comment: @TTT: it works since protocol v2. In v1 it works only if you configure your server to set `uploadpack.allowAnySHA1InWant` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks! This sovled our problemand. We now have all commits back home where they belong. :) 

- You're a legend @torek